# PayPal TLS test failed

Tags: linux, ssl, paypal

I have confirmed my server is supporting tls1.2 with the help of following command.

```
openssl s_client -connect shop.domain.org:443 -tls1_2
```

The above command returned a certificate chain and handshake.

But if I check the same with Paypal it failed with following errors. I have executed it from my server.

```
curl https://tlstest.paypal.com
```

curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to tlstest.paypal.com:443

```
 wget https://tlstest.paypal.com


--2016-03-07 11:48:29-- https://tlstest.paypal.com/
Resolving tlstest.paypal.com... 104.66.242.99
Connecting to tlstest.paypal.com|104.66.242.99|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Can somebody explain me why my test with PayPal is failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue I have modified code to the following

```
# php -r '$ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://tlstest.paypal.com/"); var_dump(curl_exec($ch));'
```

and it returned a value like

PayPal_Connection_OKbool(true)